# How to combine data and then separate concatenated data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, spread-syntax, spreadsheetgear

I would like to combine a range of data into one single cell G5.

Then I want to split  Value G5 into original form.   Thank you so much.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sVrpPvtQPG0Zw2Ar_UxPHXNN0atEdQNX-hkyB2ixUGw/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ER1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 {A1:B3&" |", C1:C3}),,9^9))&"♦",,9^9), "♦ |♦$", CHAR(10))))
```

[image]

---

ER2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(G5, CHAR(10))), "|")))
```

[image]