# Use Query formula returning a list of results in one cell then split into original form

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

This question is different with previous one.
Because my function is within query results, the previous answer won't work with a range of data from Query outputs.

I would like to use Query formula returning a list of results in one cell.

Then I want to split Value G6 into original form. Thank you so much.

I knew how to use =JOIN(), =CONCATENATE() function to generate same results. Since my data is huge, I prefer to use Query function to keep my data flexible. Thank you for helping.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SBw4CME18KNtlopHi4lBtqKuGEueH8EEiVsAy34h6BU/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine data and then separate concatenated data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73513817/how-to-combine-data-and-then-separate-concatenated-data)

Comment: not exactly the same.

Comment: how it differs from your previous question? pls explain

Comment: Because my function is within query results,   the previous answer won't work with a range of data from Query outputs.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(QUERY(A1:C3,"SELECT *")="",,
    QUERY(A1:C3,"SELECT *")&" |")),,9^9)), 
 "( \|)$", "×"),,9^9), "× |×$", CHAR(10))))
```

[image]