# How to use query to generate the result with descending order

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-query-language, textjoin

Hi I would like to generate the result with descending order.

is it possible to use Query achieve this result?  or is there alternative way ?

Thank you

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hnFi-5IRIb-hSO2YffvjR9ZETL11c8wVuCbBhC5m7qY/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&B1:D1&"×"&B2:D), "×"), 
 "where Col3 is not null order by Col3 desc", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also help with this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73531468/use-query-formula-returning-a-list-of-results-in-one-cell-then-split-into-origin